# Is there a better way to preview the addition of a new element?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

I am to preview where a new element will be added on button click. I thought about just creating the element and showing that in the preview, but I have several buttons and some of the elements they create require input (via window.prompt) so I decided to just make a placeholder div and use that instead

Javascript:

```
var addTempDiv = function (e) {
  ...
}

buttons.on('mouseenter', addTempDiv).on('mouseleave', function() {$("#NewElemPlaceholder").remove();});
```

CSS:

```
#NewElemPlaceholder {
  background: blue;
  opacity: 50%;
  height: 3em;
}

body.editMode-dontlist #editDiv {
  display: block !important;
  position: sticky;
}
```

- The buttons are in #editDiv, div above the main content with position: sticky (as shown)
- The placeholder is removed on mouseleave on the button, or on button click.
- Internally, I am storing the placeholder div in a global variable so that it can be reused.
- I haven't included the code in addTempDiv, as it's rather convoluted. But it does add the tempDiv in the right place.

-- Edit --

What makes addTempDiv convoluted is that I maintain a "lastFocused" element in the main content, and new content elements are added relative to the lastFocused element. It is also complicated because of html hierarchy: With some elements (like P's and H1's) the new element is appended *after* the element. With others (like TD) the new element should be added as a child of the TD.

The whole reason for adding the "preview" feature is that if someone is editing an ol/ul list, and then they hit "P", it will create a new paragraph under the list item (if that is the lastFocused element). But if the last focused element is an ol/ul, then the new paragraph is added after the list (in the editDiv there is a toolbar to set lastFocused to parent elements in the DOM hierarchy)

I created this technology, and even I get tripped up with exactly the case above (adding a paragraph after a list). So my idea was to add this preview/temp div so that I (and hopefully others going forward) could see where the new element would be placed before adding it.

Maybe this information should have be right at the start of my question, but then I have to get into the sticky issues of lastFocused and addTempDiv right away which I worry could confuse people looking at my question. Anyway, I've put it here.

-- End Edit --

This is currently working with all bugs fixed.

Is there a better way to preview / indicate where a new element will appear on button click? Has anyone else done this differently and can tell me about how they designed such a feature? Is this implementation going to come back and bite me?

Comment: I have an idea, but I can't be sure about it without seeing more code. Can you show the HTML structure of the `buttons` and the possible associated `NewElemPlaceholder` in relation to the buttons?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have updated my question. Hopefully my updates answer your question